# Check ontology consistency with RDFlib and python

Tags: python, rdf, owl, ontology, rdflib

I am using [RDF lib](http://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) with python. Is it there any function that controls if an ontology is inconsistent.

```
<  owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2016/1/semantic_mapping_domain_model#Chair">
    <  owl:equivalentClass rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2016/1/semantic_mapping_domain_model#Table"/>
    <  rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2016/1/semantic_mapping_domain_model#Furniture"/>
    <  owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/2016/1/semantic_mapping_domain_model#Table"/>
<  /owl:Class>
```

I have forced an individual to belong to some class and to its complement. I would like to perform a consistency check on a .owl file using python.

Starting the Pellet reasoner with Protégé returns:

> InconsistentOntologyException: cannot do reasoning on inconsistent
>   ontologies!

When I load the ontology (you can find it [here](http://userk.co.uk/ontologies/semantic_map_domain_model.owl)) with the following python code:

```
import uri
from rdflib import Graph, Literal, BNode, Namespace, RDF, URIRef
from rdflib.namespace import DC, FOAF, RDF
[...]
g = Graph()
g.parse("/local_path/scripts/semantic_mapChairs.owl")
[...]
```

nothing is detected (there is an instance of the object Chair). 
Do you have any advice?

Comment: RDFLib is, as the name implies, an RDF library. It is not an OWL reasoner.

Comment: Is it possible to use an OWL reasoner to perform a consistency check on an ontology and notify a python program about the result?

Comment: Probably you could use [tag:owlready].

Comment: Thanks I ll have look. It seems that the library supports reasoners invocation

Comment: I have this exact same requirement - owl defines the logic, but I have an independent set of rdf that contains the instances. My question on how to go about doing this using owlready2 is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74389044/owlready2-importing-in-memory-rdflib-graph

Comment: I need to check the updated documentation of both rdflib and owlready2. And fix the Deadlink too