# Owlready2: importing in-memory rdflib graph

Tags: python, rdflib, owlready

I have an ontology that defines a subject area, and have used that to help construct an rdflib graph of object instances, and their interrelating properties.

I'm using python, `owlready2` and `rdflib` libraries. I had tried constructing the instances directly in the owlready2 ontology in memory, but I need [strict control over the final IRIs (per this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74360257/owlready-conventions-for-specifying-alternate-iri-construction), hence the rdflib construction.

What I want to do next, is run a reasoner over the rdflib graph, and extract any inferred relationships that might be so generated.

Ultimately, I'll prepare a curated set of triples for entry into a final knowledge store, having run them through this process.

[Per the docs](https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/onto.html#loading-an-ontology-from-owl-files), I could save my rdflib graph to disk, and then reload it:

But this workflow might be repeated 1000 or more times in a given job, so it would be helpful to perform this step in memory.

So, is there a way I can wrap my rdflib graph such that it looks like a file and is loadable (or more strictly *importable*) by owlready2 into a unified ontology containing the class/property model *and* these new individual instances I've created - *without* having to dump it to disk, only to immediately reload it again?

Alternately [(and this appears to have been asked as a separate question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273085/check-ontology-consistency-with-rdflib-and-python) given an rdflib graph, what options do I have for running a reasoner over it, informed by a separate owl ontology?

Comment: This answer might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73023050/loading-an-ontology-from-string-in-python